# Automatically calculate (or delete) rows in Excel when first column is changing

Tags: excel, vba

I have a big table, where first columns **X** is "input column" and range it's changing.

**Y** - There are more formulas and functions (Vlookup) and 1st column X is a lookup value, and then other columns are calculated from other sheets.

```
  | A | B | C | D | E
1 | X | Y | Y | Y | Y
2 | X | Y | Y | Y | Y
3 | X | Y | Y | Y | Y
4 | X | Y | Y | Y | Y
```

I am inserting (and deleting) more X values (actual data) and then I use "double click" for all other Y columns to be calculated, BUT it's not good because the X range is not the same. I tried to convert it to table "Ctrl-T", but it's not working very good for me. Maybe I don't use it properly.

**Problem:**

If I paste a new X column, I need other Y columns to be automatically calculated OR if I delete few X rows, other Y should be also deleted. Now I get something like this:

```
  | A | B   | C   | D   | E
1 | X | Y   | Y   | Y   | Y
2 | X | Y   | Y   | Y   | Y
3 |   | N/A | N/A | N/A | N/A
4 |   | N/A | N/A | N/A | N/A
```

or:

```
  | A | B   | C   | D   | E
1 | X | Y   | Y   | Y   | Y
2 | X | Y   | Y   | Y   | Y
3 | X |     |     |     |
```

**What I need:**

If I remove X value I need automatically disappear Y values:

```
  | A | B | C | D | E
1 | X | Y | Y | Y | Y
2 | X | Y | Y | Y | Y
```

If I add X value I need automatically calculate Y values:

```
  | A | B | C | D | E
1 | X | Y | Y | Y | Y
2 | X | Y | Y | Y | Y
3 | X | Y | Y | Y | Y
```

Hope it's clear, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For Y Columns, you can add "IF" FORMULA

```
=if(A1>0,*Y COLUMN FORMULA*,"")
```

Comment: It's working! Thanks, and so simple, only one problem, excel is now toooo slow now, I am suffering :(

Comment: Toooo much, but I need all of them, Y is usually something like this: =VLOOKUP(A2;'Sheet2'!$A:$F;2;FALSE), I am "vlookuping" in 2 sheets. One sheet has 8000 rows and one more than 20 000 :D and third sheet is "result sheet" mentioned here. If I dont use IF function, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

try changing formula to

```
=iferror(*Y formula,"")
```

or if it's still slow and if you are changing only X Columns

you can use below code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Count = 1 Then 'CHECK IF THERE IS ANY CHANGE ON X COLUMN
        If Target.Value = Empty Then 'CHECK IF X COLUMN HAS BEEN DELETED
            Rows(Target.Row).Delete 'IF X COLUMN IS DELETED, DELETS WHOLE ROW
        Else
            Cells(Target.Row - 1, 2).Resize(1, 4).Copy Cells(Target.Row, 2).Resize(1, 4) 'IF X COLUMN IS ENTERED OR MODIFIED COPIES ABOVE Y COLUMN FORMULAS
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I will try later, I am not near my PC ( and let you know! :)

Comment: Uff I am not sure if I know how to use your function properly, because just copy and paste does not work (I changed it temporarily to public Sub(), but I still cannot see it in macros), can you help please? Thanks.

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_change goes to specific location.  Right click worksheet where you have X column and Y columns. Click view code. Then Paste the code to the macro editor that shows up. This will wait for your change in Column X and whenever there is a change in Column X, it will execute the code.

Comment: Just letting you know, this code will delete the whole row where Column X value is 0 including Column Y formulas in the same row. It will run faster, but If you want to keep formulas when Column X is empty, I don't recommend you using the code. And the code copies above line formulas. so if the above line is skipped, or empty, Y columns will not work